# Webapi object parameter with FromUri is null if no querystring passed

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following API Controller action

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("assets")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([FromUri]SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
{

}
```

When i test this with fiddler by accessing the url

http://localhost/assets

the searchCriteria parameter is null but when i try with

http://localhost/assets?param1=1&param2=2 then searchCriteria has got the instance of the object.

The SearchCriteria class is defined as

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
    public SearchCriteria()
    {
        Param1 = "";
        Param2 = "";
        PageIndex = 0;
        PageSize = 10;
    }
    public string Param1 { get; set; }
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
    public int PageIndex{ get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

What is wrong in my approach? Why the action parameter is null when no querystring is passed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well... because no data is present to create the parameter instance.

Look at the URLs.  Here you have values for creating the parameter:

```
http://localhost/assets?param1=1&param2=2
```

Note how `param1` and `param2` are supplied with values, which map directly to the type of the parameter:

```
public string Param1 { get; set; }
public string Param2 { get; set; }
```

But in this URL, there are no values:

```
http://localhost/assets
```

So there's nothing to use to create the instance of the method parameter.

`null` literally means "there is nothing here".  Since no parameter values were supplied, there is nothing there.

Comment: But, i am having some default values in the object. So i would like to use the default. I have updated my query.

Comment: @MukilDeepthi: In order to achieve custom behavior in this case you'd probably need to create a custom model binder for your `SearchCriteria` type.  There are a number of examples available online, and multiple ways to go about using it.  (You can use it globally in the application, or just for this action method for example.)

Comment: Can i get some example please

Comment: For some reason the `[FromUri]` parameter is null only if I specify a custom `[Route()]`. Without the custom route and relying on the default routing to reach the controller by name, the parameter value is a new instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with search criteria been null, but want to avoid unit test errors, try

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("assets")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([FromUri]SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
{

if(searchCriteria == null)
    searchCriteria = new SearchCriteria();

}
```